# Compare a MySQL table with an Excel table using Java

Tags: java, mysql, excel, apache-poi

I have a marks table with attributes `student_id` and `total_marks`. Here `student_id` refers to the primary key of student table.

I have same marks table stored as an Excel file.

Now I want to write a Java program to find out the students who are having a mismatch between data in MySQL database and Excel file.

Comment: Can you show what you've already tried?
Are you using JDBC to query your database? Are you simply reading the excel file from the file system. Is the Excel file in csv format? Is your java program a simple command line program, or does it have a UI?

Comment: Do you know how to access the table using JDBC in a Java app? Do you know how to read in an Excel file (csv format) into a Java app? If not, we have a bit of work to do.

Comment: My java program is a simple command line program with no UI. Excel file is in .xlsx format. I am using a JDBC connection to read from database and apache POI to read from excel file. Currently I am stuck with the comparison only.

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be:
query your database, and load the contents of the table into a HashMap, where the key in the HashMap is the primary key of the table. The value in the hashmap is the row associated with the primary key.

Read your excel file, and load it into a HashMap, using the primary key as the hashmap's key. The value in the hashmap is the corresponding row from the Excel file.

Next, loop through each key in the first HashMap (from the DB), and use that key to access both the DB table's HashMap, and the Excel file's Hashmap. Compare the values for these keys. At this point you should be able to "flag" any mismatches, perhaps by placing the mismatches into a separate List or HashMap.

Comment: But student_id in marks table will have multiple entries. In marks table it is a foreign key.

Comment: Please post a sample of the marks table and the excel spread sheet, and define what "mismatch" means in this context.